# Make Javascript Variable Null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have one variable in Jquery it which I am assigning the value at a button click. Now after the successful execution of the code, I want to make the variable null.

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {

var myDataVariable= {};

myDataVariable.dataOne="SomeData";
myDataVariable.dataTwo="SomeData";
myDataVariable.dataThree="SomeData";
   //Pass the value to Database
                $.ajax({
                 success: function (data) {
                   //If Successfully Inserted Data I want to make "myDataVariable" Null 
                 } 
               });
});
```

Comment: So why don't you? `myDataVariable = null;`

Comment: If you use it outside the function, move it outside the function too. If not, then no need to null it, it will be reset next time you click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {

var myDataVariable = {};

myDataVariable.dataOne="SomeData";
myDataVariable.dataTwo="SomeData";
myDataVariable.dataThree="SomeData";
   //Pass the value to Database
                $.ajax({
                 success: function (data) {
                   myDataVariable = null;
                   // you can use myDataVariable.attribute = null; if you want an attribute of this object to be null
                 } 
               });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly set it to null by applying  `myDataVariable = null;`
But I think it's unnecessary because it will automatically reset next click .